# Raise an error on collection that does not contain all items

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I'm wondering what the cleanest way is to go through a collection in RxJava syntax and raise an error if any item(s) do not exist. A hybrid example is shown below, but ideally I'd like all the logic in RxJava syntax.:

```
public Single<List<Bar>> doSomething(Collection<String> ids) {
  Single<List<Bar>> bars = getAllBars();
  List<Bar> results = bars
  .flattenAsObservable(z-> z)
  .filter(bar -> ids.contains(bar.getId())
  .toList()
  .blockingGet();// Blocking since I don't know the RxJava syntax for below

  if (results.isEmpty()) {
    throw SomeError();
  }
  if (results.size() != ids.size()) {
    // Ideally know which bar(s) are not in the ids list
    throw someError();
  }
  return Single.just(results);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this can be achieved quite simply if you propagate an error downstream if an id is not found and subscribe where ever you want to act on that error. It's also quite easy to include info about the missing bar(s) like so:

```java
public Single<List<Bar>> doSomething(Collection<String> ids) {
  return getAllBars()
    .map(bars -> {
      List<Bar> unknownBars = new ArrayList<>();
      for(Bar bar : bars) {
        if(!ids.contains(bar.getId()) {
          unknownBars.add(bar);
        }
      }
      if (unknownBars.isEmpty()) {
        return bars;
      } else {
        throw new BarsNotFoundException(unknownBars);
      }
    });
}

//elsewhere
doSomething(ids)
  .subscribe(bars -> { /* do something */ }, throwable -> { /* handle error */ });
```

If the throw statement gets reached in your map, the second lambda of your subscribe method will be executed with the error you've thrown.

What I've learned from using rx myself: When you're starting to get more comfortable with it, it starts to feel like a fancy new hammer and suddenly everything looks like a nail. Remember to only use it when it makes your life easier, not harder.

Comment: Thanks for the input!  Are you suggesting by your last paragraph that it's best to leave it as blocking like the original example?  In other words, how would you deal with the situation?

Comment: Nope, not suggesting that. What I'm suggesting is that in your original code snippet it feels you're trying to leverage your business logic to rx while that is often not needed. So instead of flattening your list of bars into an `Observable` stream, a simple `for` loop suffices, which in my opinion is simpler to read and understand (by other people not familiar with rx as well). Other than that rx is a fantastic tool to deal with any kind of asynchronous operation.

Comment: I get what you're saying :). In this case the getBars already returns rxJava stuff so I may as well go along with it vs breaking it into a hybrid.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can also have something like that:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Collection<String> ids = List.of("id4", "id2", "id1", "id3"); // same ids
    // Collection<String> ids = List.of("id4", "id2", "id1", "id5"); // different ids
    // Collection<String> ids = List.of("id4", "id2", "id1", "id3", "id5"); // different ids
    // Collection<String> ids = List.of("id4", "id2", "id1"); // different ids

    doSomething(ids)
            .subscribe(l -> System.out.println("received: " + toString((List<Bar>) l)),
                       err -> System.err.println(err.getMessage()));

    Flowable.timer(60, SECONDS) // Just to block the main thread for a while
            .blockingSubscribe();
}

private static Single<List<Bar>> doSomething(Collection<String> ids) {
    return getAllBars().flatMap(bars -> {
                           List<String> unknownBarIds = bars.stream().map(Bar::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
                           unknownBarIds.removeAll(ids);
                           return unknownBarIds.isEmpty()
                                            ? Single.just(bars)
                                            : Single.error(new Exception("unknown bars: " + unknownBarIds));
                       })
                       .flatMap(bars -> {
                           List<String> barIds = bars.stream().map(Bar::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
                           List<String> missingIds = new ArrayList<>(ids);
                           missingIds.removeAll(barIds);
                           return missingIds.isEmpty()
                                        ? Single.just(bars)
                                        : Single.error(new Exception("missing bars: " + missingIds));
                       });
}

private static Single<List<Bar>> getAllBars() {
    return Single.just(List.of(new Bar("id2"), new Bar("id1"), new Bar("id3"), new Bar("id4")));
}

private static String toString(final List<Bar> bars) {
    return bars.stream().map(Bar::getId).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

if you wish to preserve the error within the rx flow?